# Can a slave BLE device read the RSSI value of other BLE devices?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, master-slave, rssi

I know it is possible to read the RSSI value of advertising peripherals (slaves) from a center BLE device (master).
My question is about the ability of a slave BLE device to read the RSSI values of other slave devices.

Answer (score 1):

The bluetooth standard defines some terms, for example "roles", "peripheral" and "slave". Different roles have different capabilities. For example when you are in the peripheral role you can advertise and receive connection requests as a slave.

According to the standard, you cannot scan and therefore receive RSSI values from advertisements if you are not currently in the "observer" or "central" role.

However, most BLE devices supports many roles and you can often easily switch between roles. Check out the documentation for your BLE device to see what it supports.